# Custom Gutenberg Block: Excluding an allowed block from InnerBlock's templateLock={'all'}

Tags: block-editor

The title pretty much says it all. I am working on a custom Gutenberg block that utilizes the [InnerBlocks](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/360511303434aa707c507ce621d37971bf08be32/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks/README.md) component and I have defined some allowed and default blocks. I also have templateLock set to `all` so the user cannot add, remove or move blocks around. However, this settings is affecting the `core/buttons` block and your ability to add a new button (since this block made up of individual `core/button` blocks).

Is there any way around this? Is there a way to specifically exclude the `core/buttons` blocks from the templateLock setting?

Below you will find my edit function for the block.

```
edit: function (props) {
    const { className, clientId } = props;

    /**
     * Add Item
     */
    const onRemoveItem = () => {
        setAttributes({ items: parseInt(`${items}`) - 1 })
        removeBlock(clientId)
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className='listicles-innerblocks' >
                <InnerBlocks
                    template={[
                        ['core/cover'],
                        ['custom/listdt'],
                        ['core/buttons'],
                        ['custom/listdd'],
                    ]}
                    allowedBlocks={[
                        ['core/cover'],
                        ['custom/listdt'],
                        ['core/buttons'],
                        ['custom/listdd']
                    ]}
                    templateLock={'all'}
                />
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
},
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

`core/buttons` is a container block, it's not the actual buttons. Instead, `core/buttons` contains `core/button` blocks. The same way that a `core/columns` block contians `core/column` blocks.

You need to add `core/button` to your allowed blocks list.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I don't get the plus icon to add a button to the buttons core block. If I remove the templateLock then I will see the plus sign.

Comment: have you considered not fully locking the template down? There was a blog post on the official Make WP blog at wordpress.org about locking individual blocks and patterns recently in WP 5.9, right now you're passing a template but you've said nothing about the attributes or contents of the blocks in your template